# How to launch Marshmallow API 23 phone in visual studio emulator for android

Tags: android, visual-studio-emulator

May I know how to launch Marshmallow API 23 in visual studio emulator as I keep getting the message of we encountered a problem while launching this device. Below is the log file:

```
0> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0 Windows 10 Enterprise
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: alaska - 1072009
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: to be filled by o.e.m.
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: h61m-s2p
1> 6/11/2019 5:50:32 PM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: NVIDIA GeForce GT 630, Version: 23.21.13.8813
2> 6/11/2019 5:50:34 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 6/11/2019 5:50:34 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 6 Platforms: 2
2> 6/11/2019 5:50:34 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2> 6/11/2019 5:50:35 PM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5
3> 6/11/2019 5:50:46 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
3> 6/11/2019 5:50:46 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone
3> 6/11/2019 5:50:46 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
3> 6/11/2019 5:50:46 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
3> 6/11/2019 5:50:46 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
3> 6/11/2019 5:51:00 PM : [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone' device.
3> 6/11/2019 5:51:00 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe
3> 6/11/2019 5:51:00 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5.7\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 3072 /diagonalSize 5.7 /video "1440x2560" /vhd "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5.7_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5.7-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.admin" /noStart /silent
3> 6/11/2019 5:51:00 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13)
```

Hope can have a solution for it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: That is a very old version you are trying to start, do you have the same problem with a recent build?

Comment: @Simson haven't try yet. I will try the recent build and see

Comment: There are prebuilt images for the later ones which are known to work, if you can start one of those your tools are set up correctly - and the problem is related to kitkat, if the recent image does not start your problem is tools related.

Comment: @Simson i still failed to launch other api


log message shown as below:
6> 6/11/2019 1:13:06 PM : [Informational] Downloading Marshmallow (API 23): 100%
6> 6/11/2019 1:13:08 PM : [Informational] Installing platform files
6> 6/11/2019 1:15:17 PM : [Critical] Platform package installation failed. Exit Code: 1602
6> 6/11/2019 1:15:17 PM : [Critical] Platform package installation failed. Exit Code: 1602

Comment: edit and update question with your new findings. The formatting in comments are limited

Comment: @Simson ok. already update the question

Comment: `XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13)` the error is quite clear

Comment: @Zun but i try to check my hypervisor in services is running and also turn feature on or off the hypervisor is tick